# How can I calculate $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{7^{\sqrt{n}}\cdot(n/2)!\cdot(n/2)!}{n!} $?

Tags: calculus, limits

How can I calculate this limit?
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{7^{\sqrt{n}}\cdot(n/2)!\cdot(n/2)!}{n!} $$

I thought to try the ratio test, but I don't know how to do it because that I get $(\frac{n+1}{2})!$ and $(\frac{n}{2})!$ such that it's not define.

Comment: This is just a duplicate of your previous question, with no improvements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

Let apply Stirling’s approximation

$$n! \sim \sqrt{2 \pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n$$

that is

$$\frac{7^{\sqrt{n}}\cdot(n/2)!\cdot(n/2)!}{n!}\sim \frac{7^{\sqrt{n}}\left(\sqrt{2 \pi \frac n 2}\left(\frac{n}{2e}\right)^{\frac n 2}\right)^2}{\sqrt{2 \pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n}=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}\frac{7^{\sqrt{n}}  n^{n+1}}{2^nn^{n+\frac12}}=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}\frac{7^{\sqrt{n}}  n^{\frac12}}{2^n}$$

Comment: Can you explain how can I use this please?

Comment: Plug in the approximation for n! and (n/2)!

Comment: It's look that it's more complex in this form..

Comment: @AskMath I've added one step, let simplify

Comment: Ok, and now, how can I calculate it? $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{7^{\sqrt{n}}\cdot\sqrt{n}}{2^n} $

Comment: @AskMath by ratio test for example

Answer (score 0):

Let
$$
a_n=\frac{7^{\sqrt{n}}\cdot(n/2)!\cdot(n/2)!}{n!}.
$$
Consider a subsequence of this sequence given by
$$
a_{4k^2}=\frac{7^{\sqrt{(4k^2)}}\cdot((4k^2)/2)!\cdot((4k^2)/2)!}{(4k^2)!}
=\frac{7^{2k}\cdot(2k^2)!\cdot(2k^2)!}{(4k^2)!}
\leq \frac{7^{2k}(2k^2)!(2k^2)!}{(2k^2)!(2k^2)!(2k^2)!}\to 0
$$

Comment: In this way you show that if the limit exists it is 0 but how can be sure that limit exists?

Comment: @gimusi Just prove that this is a Cauchy sequence. We know that if a Cauchy sequence has a convergent subsequence, then it itself is a convergent sequence.